# Pentaho Kettle : How to use the same database connection in both Job and transformation

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I have a job and multiple transformations. If i wanted to define a database connection in the Job , and use the same database connection for all the transformations , how do I go about it ? I am using a community edition Pentaho 5.0 version .

I am creating the jobs locally using spoon and moving them to a Linux server where I will be using kitchen.sh to execute the job and transformations .

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spoon, define your database connection in **Tools > Repository > Explore > Connections**. It will be shared by all your jobs and transformations. Before that close all your jobs and transformations opened.

Comment: Or if you are just using ktr and kjb you can right click a connection and use the share option

Comment: Hi Codek , So if we use this option , this would work after deployment to the Linux servers too right ?

Comment: @rasikavijay Sharing connection will be applicable in all the env. you move to once you have shared the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not connected to a Pentaho Server Repository (you are working locally), open the transformation where yoy have already configured the connection, now in the "View" tab, "Database connections" element, select the connection and rigthclick to open contextual menu then select "Share", now the connection is available in all other open locally transformations and you can reuse it.

PDI Version 9.2